# Is a data model driven resource Id a facet of the resource or of the database?

Tags: database, model, uniqueidentifier, ownership

My examples are going to involve pseudo C# code for discussion purposes, but this is not specific to any single language or database tooling.

Take a simple model

`Customer { string Id }`

Using RavenDB when I store `new Customer()` it will generate an id for me at execution time, suppose "Customers/234". In this scenario I'm fine with accepting that id is a facet of RavenDB. Fundamentally this is absolutely no different than `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` as it creates an identifier that has no human understandable meaning and merely achieves the goal of global uniqueness (to this database). This is just arguably a nicer version of a guid, and will create better URLs and allow a human to communicate their id if it's ever needed far easier than a string of 16 random hex characters.

In another scenario take:

`User { string UserName, string Id }`

In this scenario I want to place true semantic meaning into my Id as opposed to just an unique number.

With RavenDB this could be accomplished similar to:

```
store.Conventions.DocumentKeyGenerator = (entity) => 
{
   User user = entity as User;
   if(user == null)
      return  defaultKeyGeneration (entity);

  return "Users/" + user.UserName;
}
```

Which then during this store operation you would end up with "Users/dotnetchris"

I could also approach this by instead of having User have a simple property for Id, to use a read-only property:

```
User {
    string Id { get { return "Users/" + UserName }
```

I'm having a hard time deciding which of these is the proper place for this construct.

I'm leaning towards it should be included in the class directly, as this gives you information that it will be easy to load this object by id from user input without actually needing to query to the datbase to find `Users.Where(user.UserName == "dotnetchris")`

Comment: As a side note, any point I use global I'm referring in the scope of my data, not necessarily globally unique across the world the way GUIDs **truly** are unique.

Comment: I'm actually trying to implement one of these solutions.  I like the generation being in DocumentKeyGenerator because it isolates the key generation code to a single location. However, RavenDb offers a Load which allows loading entities by Id and if you don't already have an id with the proper prefix applied then you need a way of applying the prefix outside of the key generation system.

Comment: @ShaneH I agree with you that it isolates that to the 1 location, however I'm not really sure that's a good thing as all of your objects then lose that understanding which is why I opened this question. If I needed to construct these IDs from their keyParts to satisfy Load I would likely create a class that behaves like `Id.For<User>(this.RouteData)`, inside this would be a switch on the generic type, and I'd `return "users/{userName}".HenriFormat(routeData)` https://gist.github.com/2170953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule I strive for every single identifier to be owned by the application and not the database. The only reason I will pass ownership of a model's identity is performance reasons, e.g. a SQL table that needs replicated and has 500 million rows.

Answer (score 1):

It seems highly dependent on how the data may or may not be referenced in the database. If the  "full" ID (i.e. `Users/name`) is required for some kind of constraint in the database design, then keeping it close to the database would be a better option, but if that's not the case, you will benefit more from keeping it as a piece of the domain model to allow for flexibility in the code (as per your final code sample).

Comment: Users/name guarantees global uniqueness, it is impossible for any other document to have an id of that (validly). Without Users/ the value of Name could no longer be guaranteed unique if it would get used in another type. While this was derived from the standard RavenDB conventions I agree with the underlying premise of using the type name as a delimiter. So while RavenDB might also require IDs to be unique (as there are no true tables), it is also a business requirement to able to uniquely information and I accept that this convention is as good as any, if not arguably the best period.

Comment: If uniqueness is what's necessary, then I would think that having it closer to the database would be best. In doing so the unique identifier is unique in both the database and, by necessity, the domain model. Should the `Username` portion ever be needed on it's own (in a situation where uniqueness isn't required, etc.) then it's just as easy to strip that portion out.